# Do bigger Cooking Stations give more XP per food cooked?

Tags: fallout-4

So there are a few different types of Cooking Stations, such as the small one that's basically just a pot on the ground, a slightly bigger one with a hanging pot with a seat made of concrete blocks, and then a big one with a handle you turn with two roasted animals (or parts of animals) on it.

So, with all these different types, is there an experience difference between them all? Will I get more experience if I make a Baked Bloatfly on a big Cooking Station instead of making the Baked Bloatfly on a smaller station (ignoring Intelligence level, Idiot Savant, and things of that nature)?

Answer (score 6):

From what I can gather, they each are they same. They just are different in appearance for cosmetic reasons, and take different items to make.

Here is a [Steam forum](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/496881136903558120/) where multiple people stated it doesn't matter:

> No they are exactly the same, it's just a preference and for buildings in the wasteland. Not gonna have a rotisserie inside a house.
>
> all the same, save place one and see for yourself

A [Reddit thread](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3tqlg6/do_different_crafting_stations_of_the_same_type/?client=ms-android-att-us) also says the same thing:

> It's just aesthetics. I've tried all the different cooking stations and had no difference between them.